# django orm delete object derived from another model

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following issue :

```
class A (models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=80, default="")

class B(A):
   another_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, default="")
```

How is it possible to get A automatically deleted if B is deleted ? If I work with a foreign_key and DELETE_CASCADE all is fine, but with derived models not.

Comment: How are you determining that which object of A is connected to which object of B

Comment: In the database objects of B have a pointer to objects of A

Comment: Why not write a custom delete method. It would be really simple solution

Comment: I am having the problem when using Plain SQL to delete the entries. In the table definition (SQL) the DELETE CASCADE constraint is missing.

Comment: Don't write plain SQL use orm instead

Comment: I am not using plain SQL in my django app. For maintenance purposes or during development a SQL-Databasetool is quite handy.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is possible to write your own delete() methods for model B to delete an object form model A as well.
But how should you decide/know which object A hast to be cascaded with the deletion of a specific object B if there is no ForeignKey?

Comment: When using django to delete the object the base objects are deleted. Just not at sql level. Django ORM does not set DELETE CASCADE in the database.

Comment: I don't really get it. You said - correct me if I am wrong - if a model's object is deleted with django it won't be deleted from the database? Or do you just refer to CASCADE deletion on inherited models?

Comment: I mean a inherited model is deleted from the database. If you delete it with django (or the admin) the base objects are deleted. If you use plain SQL the base objects (A in that case) are not deleted.

Comment: Objects of model A are not linked to model B anyhow. Why should any of them be deleted when model B disappears? If you want to link them you must have a relation between them. And then the relationships is between objects of those two models, not between the "entire" model B and single model A objects. You already said with ForeignKey everything is fine - what is you motivation **not** to use a foreign key?

Comment: B is derived from A. If you look at the tables created you see

Comment: I see that. But object of B are independent from objects of A. And - if I am not wrong - you want to delete objects of A if an object of B is deleted but you don't have any relationship between them.

Comment: They are linked in the DB if B is derived from A and A is of type models.Model. If you look at the tables created you see A has the columns id, name and B has the columns A_ptr_id, another name.

Comment: Now i see the problem. Did you try to initialize the on-to-one field of your derived model B? `A_ptr = models.OneToOneField(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE, parent_link=True,)`

See [django's multi-table-inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)

Comment: pls see my second answer

Comment: Did you try this with a `models.OneToOneField` (not a models.ForeignKey)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151492/discussion-between-mbieren-and-max-m).

Answer (score 0):

When using dbshell and delete B objects everything is fine. Base objects of Class B  are deleted as well (A in that case).

Django does not place DELETE CASCADE on database level. If you delete model B objects with sql A objects remain in the db.

Quite a pitty

Answer (score 0):

Info to MaxM. I want the following database constraint. Django does not create this

```
ALTER TABLE B
    ADD CONSTRAINT B_A_fkey FOREIGN KEY (A_ptr_id)
        REFERENCES A (id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

it only emulates this behavior. Your suggestions only allows me to control the name of `A_ptr_id`